# Making collections unselectable at the same time

Tags: selection-tools, collections, outliner

Is it possible to make all selected collections unselectable at the same time ? I mean, without clicking on each single arrow of each collection ? I would like that at the end all the collections except the unselected one turn out as unselectable.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + Left Click on the mouse icon to make all but the clicked collection selectable.

If you want to restore the clickability to all collections, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  + Left Click on the "isolated" collection.

[image]

Comment: For restoring clickability it's not necessary to use the _Alt_ key, just repeat left-clicking with the _Ctrl_ key like before. But, if I take the question literal and it's not a typo: is it possible to make all **selected** layers unselectable? That's something different than making **all** unselectable.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Oh, right my bad thanks :) Yup I made a choice between the title and the body of the question, you're right that it doesn't answer the question but I didn't find any shortcut to do it easily. In 3.0.0 there is a new property panel to access collection properties but you can't edit the selectability with the ALT modifier like other fields. Might get fixed soon enough

Comment: Well, the way the question is asked it really seems like all collections are meant so your answer is good, but nevertheless it would be interesting if there is a way to do this with a selection of collections that I don't know about.

Comment: I came over again on this after a few months. It is not possible to use this method for items that are inside a collection, right?

Comment: @pippooooo yeah this shortcut doesn't work for objects. You can however use ALT + CLICK on the arrow icon to set all selected objects to unselectable. You wont be able to make them all selectable again afterwards though because since they are not selectable, the ALT modifier to apply a change to multiple selected objects doesn't work anymore x)